# Deployment Task Logs in VS / TFS 2015 don't show up

Tags: tfs, build, visual-studio-2015

I'm having issues since switching to solely TFS 2015 w/ VS 2015 that the logs no longer have the details of the Deployment Task. They are still visible if I go back to a 2013 visual studio and view them in VS instead of online. However I would like to continue using the new tools provided.

[IN WEB UI]

```
Deploy Build on Environment
 Deploying Build
  Run Deployment scripts
   Run Deployment Task
    Run Deployment Task
     Deployment Task Logs for Machine: machine01
  Release Environment From Deployment
```

---

[IN VS 2013 UI]

```
Deploy Build on Environment
 Deploying Build
  Run Deployment scripts
   Run Deployment Task
    Run Deployment TaskDeployment Task Logs for Machine: XXXXX
     Accessing the following location using the lab service account: XX\XXXX, \\XXXXXX\builds.
     Executing XXXXX.bat
      C:\>xcopy XXXX XXXX
      C:\>start /wait C:\TestAutomation\Setup.exe
      set exitCode=0
      ..........
   Release Environment From Deployment
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the detailed TFS build log, please go to Diagnostics tab in web UI.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much but I have already checked this location but the info under "Deployment TaskDeployment Task Logs" does not show up under diagnostics. Please let me know if you see something different.